# ListView not initially showing data

Tags: c++, qt, listview, qml

My QML `ListView` doesn't show my data until I perturb it with the mouse (*e.g.* just drag it up and down.)  After this the view shows the model without issue until it empties, and then I once again need to perturb it to get it working again.  Is there way to kick this `ListView` into working?

I'm using Qt 5.8 on Linux 14.04.  My model is a subclass of `QAbstractListModel`.  I build it by following the [AbstractItemModel Example](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquick-models-abstractitemmodel-example.html).  The main difference is that my list model is a property of an entity, rather than being set with `setContextProperty` in `main.cpp`.

There are a few similar issues here on SO about the `ListView`s not updating, but none seem to only have an issue at the start.  Most of them relate to the OP calling `dataChanged` manually instead of `beforeInsertRows()` & `endInsertRows()` - both methods I'm calling (see below.)

My `ListView` is in an item loaded with a `SceneLoader`.

I [posted all the relevant code here](https://gist.github.com/kheaactua/13e3943e10a25f3df295148b1d2f1f86), because I'm a little suspicious of how I use the Layouts on my `ListView` (maybe that's causing it?  Maybe my hierarchy is broken?  I haven't been able to prove that though.)

In short though,

**ListView**:

```
ListView {
    anchors.fill: parent
    model: sceneGraph.blobs
    delegate: delegate
}
```

**BlobModel.cpp**:

```
auto BlobModel::addBlob(const BlobPointDataPtr& data) -> void
{
    // ...

    // Each blob has a uuid

    const auto idx = Contains(uuid);
    if (-1 != idx)
    {
        blobs_[idx]->Update(data);
        Q_EMIT dataChanged(createIndex(idx, 0), createIndex(idx, 0));
    }
    else
    {
        beginInsertRows(QModelIndex(), rowCount(), rowCount());
        blobs_ << new Blob{data, id_count_}; id_count_++;
        endInsertRows(); // responsible for the QQmlChangeSet

        Q_EMIT dataChanged(createIndex(rowCount(), 0), createIndex(rowCount(), 0));
    }
}
```

Also, on my terminal, I receive the message:

```
QObject::connect: Cannot queue arguments of type 'QQmlChangeSet'
(Make sure 'QQmlChangeSet' is registered using qRegisterMetaType().)
```

This seems to be emitted by `endInsertRows()`, but I'm not sure *why*.  In the past the solution has been to register the missing type, *e.g.* `qRegisterMetaType<QQmlChangeSet*>("QQmlChangeSet");` but this seems not to be a public type with Qt, and because everything mostly works without it, I'm not sure missing that is the exact issue.

Comment: I've tested your code as best as I could with what you provided. I replaced your Blob Object with QStrings for simplicity. I made addBlob() exactly as the AbstractItemModel Example does. It worked fine for me. [Code Here](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/1a41d90c212c73086fe81c41374b9661)

Comment: How did you populate the model?  I found that it worked fine if initial data existed in the model, the problem was really only when the model was empty (so at start up or when the model was emptied.)   Thanks for looking at it, I'll try to actually create a full minimal example, and then I'll try it with strings as in your example to see if that makes any difference.

Comment: hmm, I just set up a [minimal compilable example](https://github.com/kheaactua/listview_issue/tree/master/listview_issue), and it also works.  In the morning I'll add a little more to bring it closer to my original code to see where the issue starts (and then delete this comment)

Comment: You shouldn't modify your model from outside of the main thread.

Comment: @Grecko I need access to that data in both the QML interface and the background C++.  By not modifying it outside of the main thread, how should I populate it?  Also, my list requires that elements be removed after a length of time.  Thanks.

Comment: I populated the model in main(), before the qml was loaded, so I suppose that's why it worked for me. How are you populating the model's data? What GrecKo noted is correct. If you are multi-threading, you can retrieve/prepare data in one thread and provide it to the model via signal/slot mechanisms. Note also, if your model is editable you should be implementing setData().

Comment: @TonyClifton Yeah, initial data will prompt it into working.  Right now I have another thread that calls an `addData` method on the model (in the [minimal example](https://github.com/kheaactua/listview_issue/blob/master/listview_issue/blobs.cpp#L15) (where everything works somehow...) I call it with a `QTimer`.)  You're suggesting that I invoke this via a signal/slot?  e.g. `addData` is a slot that then inserts rows into the model?  I can give that a try.

Comment: QTimer run on GUI thread so it will update the model properly when calling your addData method. Using signals/slots is the best way I can think of to pass data to the model. (Or anywhere else for that matter)

Comment: @TonyClifton @Grecko That was the trick.  Passing my data with a signal rather than calling `addData` made all the difference.  It also got rid of the `QQmlChangeSet` error message, but required that I register the data type I am using, which is fine.  Thanks.  I'll fix up my original code and try to write a proper answer.

Answer (score 0):

The problem, as pointed out in the comments, was that I was modifying my model outside of the main thread.

My code was set up so that another thread would trigger additions to my model by directly calling `addData`.  The reason my minimal example wasn't able to replicate this was because in it I used a `QTimer` to simulate the other thread, however `QTimer` also runs on the main thread.

The solution was to change my direct call to `addData(data)` to emitted a signal to do the addition, thus moving the actual work back to the main thread.